# *ngFor does not display array data nor any error

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, typescript, express

Working with mongoDB's `$filter aggregation` currently, and it has been able to produce me the expected output from my query. The problem lies within my HTML whereas `*ngFor` does not display my data nor does it show any error within the console.

For a better understanding, this is my JSON produced from a console.log:

[image]

Below is my query code:

```
//api.js

router.get('/agent-policies/:name', (req, res) => {

    db.collection('users').aggregate([
        // Get just the docs that contain an agent element where agent is === req.params.name
        {$match: {'paPolicies.policy.agent': req.params.name}},
        {$project: {
            policy: {$filter: {
                input: '$paPolicies.policy',
                as: 'police',
                cond: {$eq: ['$$police.agent', req.params.name]}
            }},
            _id: 0
        }}
    ]).toArray((err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(results);
    })

})
```

And lastly, my template code:

```
//component.html

<div *ngFor='let police of agentPolicies'>
      {{police.relationship}}
</div>
```

where `agentPolicies` has been set as an array in my `component.ts` as:

```
agentPolicies: any = [];
```

Since the code is not producing any error, I would assume that the problem is within my HTML and I am not using *ngFor correctly. What do I change in order to display the value of `relationship` from my JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `relationship` is a property of `policy` array and first object of it. You must change your HTML as below,

```
<div *ngFor='let police of agentPolicies?.policy'>  
      {{police.relationship}}
</div>
```

**OR**

```
 <div *ngFor='let police of agentPolicies'>  
  
      <div *ngFor='let pcy of police?.policy '>  

          {{pcy.relationship}}

       </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Hey @micronyks. Thanks for the answer. Your second edit solved the problem for me. I'll be accepting this.

Answer (score 1):

This is what your API is returning:

```js
const agentPolicies = [
  {
    policy: [
      {
        relationship: '...',
        // ...
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Notice that each object has a property `policy`, which itself is an array of objects.

## Option 1: Loop through policy

With that being the case, you need to iterate through each policy array in your HTML:

```
<div *ngFor='let police of agentPolicies'>
  <div *ngFor='let policy of police.policy'>
      {{policy.relationship}}
  </div>
</div>
```

## Option 2: Modify your query in your API

If there should only be one policy per object so that your data looks like this:

```js
const agentPolicies = [
  {
    policy: {
      relationship: '...',
      // ...
    }
  }
];
```

then you need to update your query in `api.js` to return a single policy from your array coming from `$project`. Take a look at [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to find how you can replace the `policy` array with a single object from that same array.

Comment: Although I've already accepted an answer, I still appreciate a thorough explanation! Thanks for this. It is my first time using $filter aggregation that's why I was unsure.

Comment: Moreover, I've designed it in such a way that there will be multiple policies per object so this is fine just the way it is.